# React - setState of child from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components. A main and a child component.

Let's assume a function is triggered in the main component which cause its `state` to be mutated.
The `state` of the main component is passed down to the child component as a prop. The newly updated data in the `props` of the child component should now be used to to set the `state` of the child component.

I can't do this on ``componentDidUpdate since it would cause an infinite loop.
On the other hand I wouldn't want to lift the child's `state` to the main component since most code of it would be useless in the main component.

I hope you can help

Comment: why do you want to store a prop in the state? why not just use `this.prop.whatever`?

Comment: Because rendering will be dependent on the state of the child component. And the props from the main component are used for functions in the child component. Maybe, I am missing something and there is a better way?

Comment: It is unecessary to store your props in state. Setting state in props will always land you into problems. Just use the props value direcly see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor. and https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidUpdate` takes `prevProps` as argument `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)`. So to not getting the code in infinite loop, you can compare `this.props` with `prevProps` and update the state accordingly.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(this.props.data !== prevProps.data) {
     // update the new state here this will not cause infinite loop
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getDerivedStateFromProps` as mentioned in the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops):

```js
export default class Child extends Component {

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(newProps, currentState) {
        return {
            value : newProps.value
        }   
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 {/* Your layout */}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a functional component using hooks.

```
function Child(props) {

    const [whatever, setWhatever] = React.useState(props.whatever);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setWhatever(props.whatever);
    }. [whatever]);
}
export default Child;
```

Hope it helps.